# Creating Dynamic SELECT query using simple JDBC

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I want to create SELECT query dynamically. Want to add columns to the SELECT query dynamically.
If there any way of doing it by just using normal JDBC.

I tried creating the same using Table Bean class by checking not null values,
Bean bean = new Bean();
bean.setAttribute1("AAA");

and then 
in DN manager class

```
if (bean.attribute1 != null) {
 append("COLUMN_1")
}
```

similarly while loading from resultset

```
if (bean.attribute1 != null) {
 rs.getString("COLUMN_1");
}
```

but this solution involves lots of if else conditions.
suppose if there are 50 attributes present in the bean then that means 100 if else conditions
50 for creating the query and 50 for loading it from result set.

Could someone suggest me a simpler solution?

Answer (score 0):

[java.sql.DatabaseMetadata](http://www.java2novice.com/jdbc/database-metadata/) might help to generate valid query dynamically (e.g. inserts, update by primary key ).
[java.sql.ResultSetMetadata](http://www.java2novice.com/jdbc/result-set-metadata/) can to be used for query introspection (select).

Comment: I want to create SELECT query dynamically

Comment: I think it will be too complicated anyways but template engine can help (Velocity is a very mature tool) see here for usage examples http://cayenne.apache.org/docs/3.0/scripting-sqltemplate.html

Comment: Is there no other easy way of doing it?

Comment: It was always complicated to generate dynamic SQL in my practice, It needs tools  on top of JDBC or to avoid dynamic queries.